# Can't make Ubuntu think I've installed TeX Live

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu

I followed this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/861 to install texlive on Ubuntu 14.04, until when I try to make Ubuntu think I've installed TeX Live:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2014-1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-local.
dpkg: regarding texlive-local_2014-1_all.deb containing texlive-local:
 texlive-base conflicts with texlive-common
  texlive-local provides texlive-common and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive texlive-local_2014-1_all.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing texlive-local
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texlive-local_2014-1_all.deb
```

What did I do wrongly? Thanks.

I remember I might have installed some texlive related packages for installing some pdf programs. Are the following installed before I install texlive following the above post? What should I do with them then?

```
$ dpkg -l | grep texlive
ii  texlive-base                                          2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: Essential programs and files
ii  texlive-binaries                                      2013.20130729.30972-2build3                         amd64        Binaries for TeX Live
ii  texlive-font-utils                                    2013.20140215-2                                     all          TeX Live: Graphics and font utilities
ii  texlive-luatex                                        2013.20140215-1                                     all          TeX Live: LuaTeX packages
```

It seems `texlive-common` is in `texlive-base`. So I remove `texlive-base`, and the problem seems gone. I hope there won't be any problem.

Comment: Skimming the log, there are some conflicts. Are there any remaining parts of a former `apt-get` install that may be disturbing?

Comment: Possibly. I remember I installed some texlive related package for installing a pdf program. See the output of dpkg.